# output voltage of an operational amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, saturation

A student designs an electronic sensor to monitor whether the temperature in a refrigerator
is above or below a particular value. The circuit is shown below.
[image]

Question: An operational amplifier (op-amp) is used as the processing unit. Describe the function
of this processing unit.

Solution: gives a high or a low output / +5 V or –5 V output
dependent on which of the inputs is at a higher potential

My enquiry: Can the output value be between +5 V to -5 V in this case? Or should it only be saturated( +5V or -5V) because this is an ideal op-amp? Or should it be saturated because of other reasons such as: there is no negative feedback to reduce gain. Hence, it has to be saturated. So that, only types of circuits (op-amps), which can be both saturated and non-saturated are those with negative feedback -only inverting and non-inverting amplifiers.

To be more specific, my question is that which type of circuit can the output voltage be saturated or non-saturated.

Thank you very much for your help. My writing is quite poor. If you don't understand anything, please leave a comment. I would try my best to clarify.><

Comment: Yes, it is always saturated as there is no negative feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ideally*, the output will always be saturated.  This is because a ideal opamp has infinite gain.

Back here in the real world, there are some issues with this circuit:

There is always some inevitable noise on any signal.  When the temperature is close to the threshold, then this noise will cause the temperature signal to go back and forth between being above and below the threshold.  This will make the opamp output appear to be at a in-between level.

If the noise is fast enough, the opamp output will actually be at a in-between level most of the time due to the finite output voltage slew rate.  Put another way, the opamp can't go instantly from full high to full low.  If you keep jerking it around faster than it can react to, it will spend most of its time going back and forth without getting to either extreme.

To be a useful circuit, there really should be some *hysteresis*.  This is a little positive feedback.  It creates a little dead band around the threshold.  For example, if the threshold is set to 0 V, then it might take +100 mV to go high when low, then -100 mV to go low once high.  The size of the hystersis band should be enough to cover most ordinary noise.  That prevents the case described in #1, above.

There should be a resistor in series with the opamp output, or each LED.  If the opamp were perfect, it would drive the output to either +5 V or -5V.  That would blow up the LEDs.  With a real opamp, you don't know what might get damaged.

The right resistor allows for the desired current thru the LEDs.  For example, let's say these are typical green LEDs that drop 2.1 V and you want to run them at 10 mA.  When the opamp puts out 5 V, then the resistor is dropping 2.9 V.  From Ohm's law, (2.9 V)/(10 mA) = 290 Ω.  The common value of 300 Ω would be a reasonable choice then.

Answer (score 0):

You are right there is no negative feedback to reduce gain which typically will be very high say 100k for a 741 op-amp. Therefore it will saturate. A real op-amp or comparator will have an input offset  depending on how it is designed but lets say 5mV and will depend on many factors such as manufacture and temperature and noise. Therefore this will be a limitng factor on the accuracy and obviously will saturate always to one extreme.

To answer your second question  a comparator will act in the same way since the opamp in your diagram is configured to act like a comparator.